# Viewing mssql database Transactions (inserts and updates)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a block of sql script inside a transaction and I would like to view the history for this block of transaction (all the inserts and updates that was done). How can achieve this?

Comment: This question isn't clear: do you want to see what statements were executed or do you want to see affected rows (inserted, deleted or updated) or both ?

Comment: I would like to see what was inserted and updated

Comment: @Nation you need to code triggers in tables involved. Or you can change this script inside transaction you mentioned?

Comment: I think, the OUTPUT clause could help http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2183/using-insert-output-in-a-sql-server-transaction/

Comment: You might consider using the OUTPUT clause in your INSERT/UPDATE statements to insert the after images of the inserted/update rows into a temp table or table variable.  You can then select from the temp table/variable to determine the affected rows.